# What is the time complexity of this reverseWords algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to find the big oh notation and space complexity of this algorithm

```
public String reverseWords(String s) {
String result = "";
int i = 0;
int size = s.length();
while(i < size){
    while(i < size && s.charAt(i) == ' ') i++;
    if(i >= size) break;

    int j = i+1;
    while(j < size && s.charAt(j) != ' ') j++;

    String word = s.substring(i,j);
    if(result.length() == 0) result = word;
    else result = word +" "+ result;
    i = j+1;
}
return result;
```

}

My guess is the first while loop will take 0(n) and we have another two nested while loop, so in total, we have o(n^2) is that right ? and space complexity will be 0(n) becuase we saving in string.

Comment: Since every index is traversed at most two times one in the loop and one during substring. So the overall complexity will O(n) for both.

Comment: To get an idea, you could simply profile the code with different input sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasoning you use to justify O(n^2) is wrong. Nested loops do not in general imply O(n^2).

Here, `i` is incremented until it finds a non-space character (or the end of the string), and then `j` continues from where `i` leaves off, to find the first space character (or end of string). Subsequently, `i` starts from where `j` leaves off. This means that `i` and `j` iterate over the string exactly once, so the combination of the loops is linear.

However, you construct the final string using `result = word + " " + result;`. If these string concatenations require a new string to be constructed each time, you will experience O(n^2) runtime in the worst case.

To avoid the quadratic behavior (although sometimes the compiler can be clever and optimize your code to avoid the quadratic behavior on its own) you typically need to use a string builder, which will be provided by your language's standard library (eg: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html in java).

Answer (score 1):

In worst case each word would be of single character. Lets assume finding Substring takes some constant time lets say C. then computation cost for entire program is ..

```
 = n * C  where n is the number of words

 = O(n)     worst case time complexity.
```